# How to updated the lastly added data to a array of objects in mongo db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Here is my data

```
{
"userId": "xyzzzz",
"items": [{
    "addedToCartOn": 1536131159,
    "itemName": "Chicken Sausage Pizza (Personal)",
    "sku": "Ch-Pi-No-No-rIotXAkFXe",
    "addOnsAdded": 1,
    "quantity": 1
}, {
    "addedToCartOn": 1536131159,
    "itemName": "Chicken Sausage Pizza (Personal)",
    "sku": "Ch-Pi-No-No-rIotXAkFXe",
    "addOnsAdded": 1,
    "quantity": 1
}]
 }
```

Now i want to increase the "quantity" of the data which is lastly added to the items array.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: I did it by getting the data in one query and sorting the array by time stamp. Then updating the 0th index of the sorted array. But i want to do it in one query if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this if you know the index of the last item. In this case it is 1

```
db.collection.update({"userId": "xyzzzz"},{$set:{"items.1.quantity":2}})
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not very dynamic

Comment: Index is unknown. I need to update the lastly added data to that array